# Grafia do particípio passado irregular do verbo “pegar”

Tags: ortografia, conjugações

O verbo ***pegar*** admite um particípio passado irregular, mesmo que a tradição diga que a forma correta seja *pegado* (o que pode soar estranho culturalmente). A grafia correta tem acento, agudo ou circunflexo, ou não? É ***pego, pégo*** ou ***pêgo***?

Encontrei [um artigo](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI206216,31047-Pego+e+ou+pego+e) bacana sobre o assunto mas apenas no que tange a pronúncia (**pêgo** ou **pégo**). Mas e quanto à grafia? Tem acento ou não?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A grafia correta é ***pego***. Isto é válido quer na grafia atual, quer na imediatamente anterior ao acordo ortográfico de 1990. De acordo com o [artigo do Gramaticalhas referido na pergunta](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI206216,31047-Pego+e+ou+pego+e), a pronúncia correta do ***e*** é com timbre fechado, embora recentemente se tenha também divulgado a pronúncia com timbre aberto. Isto, no Brasil, que em Portugal só se usa o particípio regular *pegado*.

Aliás, existe a grafia única ***pego*** partilhada por várias palavras independentemente de o ***e*** ter timbre aberto (*eu pego*, particípio passado irregular ‘moderno’ de *pegar*, ponto mais fundo de um rio) ou fechado (particípio passado irregular ‘tradicional’ de pegar, pássaro macho da pega).

Na grafia atual não levam acento quaisquer palavras paroxítonas (com tónica na penúltima sílaba) acabados em conjunto vocálico simples ***a, e*** ou ***o*** e respetivos plurais (mas *bênção, orégão*, etc.). Na grafia anterior havia algumas exceções a esta regra (como *pêlo*, ‘cabelo’, versus *pelo*, *por + o*) mas *pego* não era uma delas. As regras da atual acentuação gráfica da paroxítonas estão na Base IX do [Acordo Ortográfico.](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990)

Comment: De onde será que eu tirei isso então? Bom, mais uma pro *KB* da Comunidade

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Talvez dalguma publicação anterior a 1945. Antes desse ano usavam-se acentos para distinguir *pêgo* de *pégo*, etc.

Comment: @Jacinto O artigo a que ele ligou na pergunta indica que a mudança ocorreu em [1971](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Lei_Federal_do_Brasil_5765_de_1971). O acordo de 1945 só se aplicou em Portugal.